# Tool recommendation for cutting curve in tiles

Tags: tile, cutting

I need to cut curve in a few tiles. The solution I have found is to use a Dremel rotary tool with a [diamond wheel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004UDI9). But I have read some reviews that most recent Dremels are not the same as the ones 5-6 years before, so I am not sure whether to buy it.

Are there better alternatives for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are basically saying "They don't make them like they used to". Which is always true. Some things get better, some get cheaper. Many companies make pencil grinders and you don't have to buy a Dremel. Look for something of a quality level and price that matches your purpose and budget.

If you only have a few small cuts to make you might consider a coping saw with an abrasive tile blade. You can also use a set of tile nippers to carefully remove small chunks of tile from a corner or edge.

If you have holes to make for pipes, they sell abrasive hole saws made for tile.

Good luck!

Comment: There are different quality models of Dremel tools. Some have bushings (cheaper) some have true bearings but are more expensive. I made the mistake of buying a cheap one thinking it was a really good sale and it barely lasted 1 job. That's when I found out about the bearing / bushing models purchased a higher quality model and it has worked fine for several years.

Answer (score 0):

curve cuts are easilyy made with 4 1/2 inch angle grinders, take your time and work into the curves slowly and it will be fine. theres also ring saws made for scroll work. if its thicker material with tighter circle in the middle the conturing blades for same grinder work also.